# In Akka Java actor model, can a router create actors with non-default constructor?

Tags: akka, actor, default-constructor

In Akka Java actor model, if I have a RoundRobinRouter, when its `tell()` method is called, I want the router (as the master) to create children actors with non-default constructor because I need to pass in some parameters.  How can I do this?

I understand that I can an actor with non-default constructor using `Props`, but how is it used when the master actor is a router?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The props in the construction of a Router is the props for the routees of that router, not the router itself.

You could simply do something like:

```
system.actorOf(new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
    public UntypedActor create() {
      return new MyActor("foo", "bar");
    }
  }).withRouter(...))
```

And all the routees will be of type MyActor with the specific constructor called.

You can do anything with the Props that you normally can. For more information see [The Akka Docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/untyped-actors.html#props)

Comment: could that be used to create a several actors dependent on a broadcast router where each actor in that set has different parameters in the constructor? I am concerned about actors getting the same parameters after being restarted.