# How to create routers in akka with parameterized actors?

Tags: scala, constructor, routes, akka

I am trying to use a broadcast router in Scala, if I'm not mistaken it should look like this:

```
val system = ActorSystem("My beautiful system")
val workerRouter = system.actorOf(Props[Agent].withRouter(BroadcastRouter(individualDefinitions.size)), name = "agentRouter")
```

That is what I understand from [the tutorial I am following](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html).

The workerRouter acts as another actor and I can send messages to this router that will send them to all the Agents (as many as individualDefinitions I have).

The problem is that I'd like to use the individual definitions to build the agents, they actually take some parameters in the constructor and those parameters are in the individualDefinitions.

**Q:** How could I tell the router to pass those parameters to each one of them as part of the constructor?

Please note each actor should get one individualDefinition and they are all different. I cannot use the solution in a related question where the constructor receives constants: [In Akka Java actor model, can a router create actors with non-default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889490/in-akka-java-actor-model-can-a-router-create-actors-with-non-default-constructo)

Please note that here each actor should have different parameters, if one of them is restarted it should get the same parameters it got in the first place. I don't know if that solution could be modified to do that.

A possible solution could be using an actor as the router, to separate creation (constructor) and routing, as in question [Akka (java), non blocking broadcast to all children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721741/akka-java-non-blocking-broadcast-to-all-children).

I'm not sure that is the "right" approach in this case. Using an actor as the router has several problems (besides of elegance). I am concerned about the actor that works as a router being restarted and losing all its subscribers. If the actor is restarted in half of a loop some actors could also miss some messages if I'm not mistaken.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create routers by specifying as routees some already created actors, constructed by whatever logic.

The following example will create 2 actors created differently and then create a round robin router which will route the messages to them.

```
class MyActor(param1: String) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case msg => log.info("Message from {}: {}", param1, msg)
  }
}

object MyActor {
  def apply(param: String): Props = Props(new MyActor(param))
}

object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem()

  val a1 = system.actorOf(MyActor("actor1"))
  val a2 = system.actorOf(MyActor("actor2"))

  val routerProps = Props.empty.withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(routees = Vector(a1, a2)))

  val router = system.actorOf(routerProps)

  for (i <- 1 to 10) {
    router ! i
  }

  readLine()
  system.shutdown()
}
```

More details here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala/routing.html

Comment: Great, that solves it and I've learnt a bit more about Akka. Tutorials should have links to the documentation ;) (sorry for that)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Master extends UntypedActor {
     -----
     -----
    public Master() {
        workerRouter = this.getContext().actorOf(Worker.createWorker().withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(8)), "workerRouter");
    }
```

With Akka 2.4.2, we can simply use:

```
workerRouter = this.getContext().actorOf(new RoundRobinPool(noOfWorkers).props(Props.create(Worker.class)), "workerRouter");
```

This is best Effort code executed in min. time in akka .