# Possible to specify custom Routees or custom constructor arguments for each Actor

Tags: java, akka

I imagine this might not be possible because of supervision strategies needing to recreate actors, nevertheless am I able to feed custom actors to a Router? Or at the very least: custom constructor arguments?

If no, why doesn't akka allow this? Is routing not suppose to be used in this way? I am using a BalancingPool by the way.

This seems to be possible in Scala [How to create routers in akka with parameterized actors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339082/how-to-create-routers-in-akka-with-parameterized-actors) but I haven't been able to figure this out in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with a pool, since a pool creates multiple instances of from the same `Props` definition, but it is possible with routing in general. From the docs:

> This type of router actor comes in two distinct flavors:
>
> - Pool - The router creates routees as child actors and removes them from the router if they terminate.
> - Group - The routee actors are created externally to the router and the router sends messages to the specified path using actor selection,
>     without watching for termination.

Do if you create a group rather than a pool, the group can contain whichever actors you want.

Comment: So @JeanLogeart's method wont work for a balancing pool, that's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Routing documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/routing.html):

```
public class Master extends UntypedActor {

    Router router;
    {
    List<Routee> routees = new ArrayList<Routee>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ActorRef r = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(Worker.class));
        getContext().watch(r);
        routees.add(new ActorRefRoutee(r));
    }
    router = new Router(new RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), routees);
    }
// ...
}
```

So you can create the routees the way you want.

Comment: Thank you this is a good method for a Group as @mattinbits says, but it wont work for pools.