# When routees are created manually for a router, how are they restarted by the supervision strategy?

Tags: java, akka

When one creates routees manually as done in this question I asked [Possible to specify custom Routees or custom constructor arguments for each Actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459820/possible-to-specify-custom-routees-or-custom-constructor-arguments-for-each-acto/32459918#32459918). How does the supervision get handled when a routee needs to be restarted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Supervision documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/routing.html#Supervision):

> Routees that are created by a pool router will be created as the router's children. The router is therefore also the children's supervisor.
>
> The supervision strategy of the router actor can be configured with the supervisorStrategy property of the Pool. If no configuration is provided, routers default to a strategy of “always escalate”. This means that errors are passed up to the router's supervisor for handling. The router's supervisor will decide what to do about any errors.
>
> Note the router's supervisor will treat the error as an error with the router itself. Therefore a directive to stop or restart will cause the router itself to stop or restart. The router, in turn, will cause its children to stop and restart.
>
> It should be mentioned that the router's restart behavior has been overridden so that a restart, while still re-creating the children, will still preserve the same number of actors in the pool.
>
> This means that if you have not specified supervisorStrategy of the router or its parent a failure in a routee will escalate to the parent of the router, which will by default restart the router, which will restart all routees (it uses Escalate and does not stop routees during restart). The reason is to make the default behave such that adding withRouter to a child’s definition does not change the supervision strategy applied to the child. This might be an inefficiency that you can avoid by specifying the strategy when defining the router.
>
> Setting the strategy is easily done:

```
final SupervisorStrategy strategy =
    new OneForOneStrategy(5, Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES),
Collections.<Class<? extends Throwable>>singletonList(Exception.class));
final ActorRef router = system.actorOf(new RoundRobinPool(5).
    withSupervisorStrategy(strategy).props(Props.create(Echo.class)));
```